# Switching to postgresql in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to switch over to PG from sqlite, it seems to work for the server itself but not the rails console.

Database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
host: localhost
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
<<: *default
database: coin-devel
```

I have also removed sqlite from the gemfile and ran bundle.

from console:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?)
```

Seems like he's still trying to use Sqlite for some reason I can't figure out.

Comment: try `spring stop` and then enter rails console

Comment: Did you add `gem 'pg'` install it and reload console/server?

Comment: "spring stop" seemed to fix it! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

try following steps:

1. Add following code in `Gemfile`

   gem 'pg'
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Set below configuration in `config/database.yml` file

   ```
   default: &default
     adapter: postgresql
     host: localhost
     pool: 5
     timeout: 5000
     username: username #username of pg
     password: password #password of pg

   development:
     <<: *default
     database: coin-devel
   ```
4. Run `rake db:create`

Answer (score 0):

"spring stop" worked. as per nattfodd's comment